# Has L'Hopital's Rule been studied as an operator?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I discovered while teaching Calc 2 that if you apply L'Hopital's rule to $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$  you get $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$, and if you apply L'Hopital *again* you get $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ back.  In other words the L'Hopital *operator* has a cycle of order two.

EDIT (Thanks KennyTM): "I suppose the L'Hopital operator should be defined on equivalence classes of pairs $(f(x),g(x))$ of differentiable functions with the fractional equivalence:  $(f(x),g(x))\equiv(h(x),k(x))$ if and only if $fk=gh$."  *This does not work*.  But it doesn't really take pairs of functions to pairs of function, either.  So the first problem is to find out *how* it is an operator.

Has anyone ever studied this operator?  Wikipedia tells me nothing.

Yes, I know it is easier to find the limit by dividing through by $x$, but some students want to apply L'Hopital to *everything*.

Comment: Well, a Taylor expansion of the denominator of your original function about a point c would go like √(1+c²)+c(x-c)/√(1+c²)+… so that's one source of your observed behavior.

Comment: I wonder if this operator can be well-defined, e.g. $(x, x^2) \mapsto (1, 2x)$ but $(x^2, x^3) \mapsto (2x, 3x^2) \equiv (2, 3x)$ but clearly $(1, 2x) \not\equiv (2, 3x)$.

Comment: @KennyTM You are right.  I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: What do you mean by "In other words the L'Hopital operator has a cycle of order two."?? That its square is the identity operation? If you apply L'Hopital twice to sinxx\frac{sin x}{x}, you do not get back the same thing. There are examples when it needs to be applied a number of times to get a simple expression. So the operator is not periodic. And again, if you want to define the operator formally, there is a pre-condition that both the numerator and the denomiator should vanish at the point.

Comment: @George S. I meant that it has an orbit of length 2 in its action on whatever it is acting on, which at this point I am not sure of!

Answer (score 2):

I dunno if its been studied as a differential operator, and I kind of doubt it, but I think you could define it in a way similar to the way that you suggested.

You consider two pairs (f,g) and (h,k) equivalent if $f/g = h/k$ or rather $fk = gh$. Then the operator L acts on equivalence classes by the following operation:

$ L(f,g) = (Df, Dg) $

But for this operator to be well defined we must enforce that $L(h,k)$ is equivalent to $L(f,g)$. This means that we must have

$Df/Dg = Dh/Dk$.

This is not always true. Suppose that $(f,g) = (x, x^2)$ which is equivalent to $(h,k) = (1,x)$.

$Df/Dg = \frac{1}{2x} \neq 0 = Dh/Dk$

So the L'Hospital operator is well defined on the equivalence classes of pairs $(f,g)$ with $g$ non-constant with the equivalence relation:

$(f,g)$ equiv $(h,k) \Leftrightarrow fk = hg $ and $ Df Dk = Dh Dg $.